# php make new array from old array

Tags: php, arrays

I have some cases where I need to do a split item for my shipment from items order.
the rule is max weight per 1 shipment is 5.
this is my items order :

```
$items = [
    [
        "sku"       => "SKU-A",
        "name"      => "Product A",
        "weight"    => 7,
        "dimension" => "20x30x10"
    ],
    [
        "sku"       => "SKU-B",
        "name"      => "Product B",
        "weight"    => 4,
        "dimension" => "10x10x20"
    ],
];
```

after doing split, i expect the result to this:

```
// will create new array
// limit weight per shipment max 5kg
$item1 = [
    [
        "sku"       => "SKU-A",
        "name"      => "Product A",
        "weight"    => 5,
        "dimension" => "20x30x10"
    ]
];

$item2 = [
    [
        "sku"       => "SKU-A",
        "name"      => "Product A",
        "weight"    => 2,
        "dimension" => "20x30x10"
    ], // this item from SKU-A where w => 7 - 5 = 2 
    [
        "sku"       => "SKU-B",
        "name"      => "Product B",
        "weight"    => 3,
        "dimension" => "10x10x20"
    ],
];

$item3 = [
    [
        "sku"       => "SKU-B",
        "name"      => "Product B",
        "weight"    => 1,
        "dimension" => "10x10x20"
    ],// this item from SKU-B where w => 7 - 5 = 2 
];
```

what's the posible way to do that? thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Mathieu27 i still cant figure it out how to do a complex loop but doing a reguler loop

Comment: Why do you want to split **SKU-B** weight of which is **4** and within the prescribed limit of **5**?

Comment: @Raky i just think to insert SKU-A (weight = 2 after limit) to item 2, and if add SKU-B will more than limit

Comment: You will need to iterate through `$items()` to check value of of each items weight for being more than 5 and then iterate till new elements are created in a new array for that item to be within prescribed limit of 5. There is no readymade tool for such splitting but mere hardcoding has to be done, However, you may dynamically assign the value of **5**.

Comment: @Raky do you have any sample code?

Comment: How do you know the weight of each item? If the weight of one unit of Product A is, say, 2, then your proposed split in the data you've posted won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@catLovers, I have made this code as desired... Please improvise/ optimise as necessary.

```
$items = [
             [
                 "sku"       => "SKU-A",
                 "name"      => "Product A",
                 "weight"    => 7,
                 "dimension" => "20x30x10"
             ],
             [
                 "sku"       => "SKU-B",
                 "name"      => "Product B",
                 "weight"    => 4,
                 "dimension" => "10x10x20"
             ],
         ];
        
         $newItems = array();
         for ($x = 0; $x <= count($items)-1; $x++) {
          if ($items[$x]['weight'] > 5) {
             $weight = $items[$x]['weight'];
             $wt =5;
            do {
                $temp = array([
                 'sku'       => $items[$x]['sku'],
                 'name'      => $items[$x]['name'],
                 'weight'    => $wt,
                 'dimension' => $items[$x]['dimension']
                 ]);
                array_push($newItems,$temp);
                $weight=$weight-5;
                if ($weight <=5){ $wt=$weight;}
            
                } while ($weight <= 5);
             echo "<pre>";
             print_r($temp);
             echo "</pre>";
           }
           else {
           array_push($newItems,$items[$x]);
          
          }
         }
         echo "<pre>";
         print_r($newItems);
         echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: @catLovers,  You need to acknowledge and Vote.